# What to do if you haven't yet davened mincha and an important rabbi calls you 10 minutes before shekia?

Tags: rabbis

Do you skip mincha and pray arvit twice?

Do you ask the rabbi to call back because you have to daven mincha?

Do you ignore the phone and callback?

Comment: i don't think you can intentionally skip and then rely on being allowed to  daven tashlumin. Why wouldn't you just answer and explain?

Comment: I'm pretty sure an important rabbi would understand the need to say mincha.

Comment: How long is the conversation? BeDi'avad one can pray with *Be'in HaShemashot*, which gives you 20+ minutes to start the 'Amidah.

Comment: I think you need to edit the question to provide better context. An *important* rabbi would understand your need to daven mincha, and for that matter, his need too (if he hasn't davened, yet.) OTOH, if he asks you to do an important mitzvah that can't be postponed, that's a different story. But, then, again, perhaps you may be allowed to do that even for a *shlemazel* rabbi.

Comment: If you know what to do, do it. If you don't, ask him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Praying arvit twice only works bdi eved (after the fact) - my approach would therefore be to explain the need to daven minha and call back afterwards